# ¿Cómo activar seleccionar todo el texto en VSCode con clic derecho del ratón?

Tags: vscode, sublimetext3

Estoy migrando de **SublimeText3** a **VSCode**, en Sublimetext al dar clic derecho del ratón me aparece la opción de seleccionar todo el código para luego copiar, pero en VSCode no, solo aparece *copiar* /  *pegar*.

¿Cómo puedo configurar VSCode para que cuando haga clic derecho con el ratón me aparezca esta opción en VSCode? de seleccionar todo el código con el clic derecho del ratón.

Comment: En la documentación de vscode tiene como crear atajos de teclado personalizados https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: Dentro de Visual Studio Code, podes hacerlo con un atajo de teclado, `cmd+a` si estas en Mac, o `ctrl+a` si estas en Windows